# ANDROID - Numeric keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, numeric

Good afternoon.

I have an EditText that may contain numbers and letters. By deploying the keyboard, is there any way to deploy it in numerical form?.

If I put the EditText as numeric I do, but that's not my case.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you doing this in code?  Do you mean that you haven't tagged the EditText as numeric but you want to show numeric keyboard under some circumstances?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
EditText myEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
myEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
```

Then set it back to alphanumeric when you are done with numeric..

Comment: Needs to include InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER like this:  
  
myEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);

Answer (score 1):

You can:

- Hide/Show different EditTexts that have different input types
- Dynamically set the input type of your EditText as needed (editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_WHATEVER)

You cannot:

- Default an IME on an EditText with inputType text to the "Numeric" layout.

Answer (score 1):

Using XML:

```
   <EditText 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/edittext"
        android:inputType="number"/>
```

or

Using code:

```
EditText editText=new EditText(this);
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your oncreate method you can put this bloc of code :

```
final EditText myEditJava = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEdit);

    myEditJava.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
                if (s.toString().matches("((-|\\+)?[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?)+"))
                    myEditJava.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);
                else
                    myEditJava.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);

        }
    });
```

So when you put the first char if It will be a Numeric Value the keyborad will be displayed on the Numeric input mode , else on text input mode.