# Simulate key press on an Android device

Tags: android, keyboard

Clicking on an EditText, the device displays the keyboard. Is there any way, in code, I can simulate a key press? I want to use it to click on the button that changes the alphabetical keyboard pad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

View.dispatchKeyEvent for example

Comment: do you know how to create one of these from a view class.. or an onclick listener?

Answer (score 1):

Is your goal to change the type of keyboard that is displayed (e.g. numeric instead of alphabet)?

If that's what you're going for, you can simply set the "[numeric](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3anumeric)" property on the TextView.

Answer (score 1):

already tried smth like this?

```
Instrumentation inst = new Instrumentation();
            for ( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i ) {
                inst.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU);
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                inst.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK);
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            }
```

like [original](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8696700/304270) author wrote there

hope you find it useful..cheers

Answer (score 0):

Your app cannot manipulate the IME keyboard like that.  You need to set the input type in code and let the device do what it wants to do.  This question looks very similar to your other question: [ANDROID - Numeric keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9912548/android-numeric-keyboard)